# When I create new package and add two or more box, all boxes id is going to be same to the last boxes id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I create new package and add two or more box, all boxes id is going to be same to the last boxes id. I wanna do all this boxes have different id. for example first box id=pack0, second box id=1 ect.

```
    function Pack() {  
    Pack.id = "pack" + packList.length;
    Pack.items = [];
    Pack.ShipTo = 0;
    Pack.ShipFr = 0;
    packList. push(Pack);
    document.getElementById("packCount").value = packList.length;

    var pkgs = document.getElementById("packages")
}

Pack.items = [];
Pack.ShipTo = 1234;
Pack.ShipFr = 9876;
var packList = [];

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}


function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  // Pack.items.pop(ev.target.id)
}


function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    var itemToMove = document.getElementById(data);
    ev.target.appendChild(itemToMove);  
}


function checkAdult(idToFind) {
    for (i = 0;packList.length;++i)
    {
                   if( packList[i].id == idToFind)
                {
                return packList[i];
                }
    }
return null;
}


function createPackageClick(e) {


    var itm = document.getElementById(packList[0].id);
    var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
    cln.id = "pack" + packList.length;

    itm.parentNode.appendChild(cln);
    // Clean Images of Source div
    var imageHolder = cln.querySelector(".items");


    while (imageHolder.children.length > 0) {

        imageHolder.removeChild(imageHolder.children[0]);
    }

     var pack=Pack();
   console.log(cln.id + " package created. We Have " + packList.length + " packages.");
    return false;   
}

function deletePack(e) {
    if (packList.length < 2) return false;
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    while (e.getElementsByTagName("img").length > 0) {
        main.appendChild(e.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]);
    }
    Pack.items = [];
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    packList.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.visualItem == e.id) {
        packList.pop(entry);
        }
    });
    for (index = 0; index < packList.length; ++index) {
       packList[index].id = "pack" + index;
    }
    document.getElementById("packCount").value = packList.length;   
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Button1").click(function() {
        var data = new Array();
        $("div .bag div").each(function(index) {
            data[index] = "'" + this.innerHTML + "'";
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'packman.aspx/ChangePackaging',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{ products:[' + data.join() + ']}',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(results) { alert(results.d); },
            error: function() { alert('error'); }
        });
    });
    var pack = Pack();
    debugger;
});
```

and asp.net code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .package {width:550px;min-height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa; position:relative; margin-top:20px; }
        .package .items { min-height:70px;}
        .package div label {display:inline-block; width:130px;}
        .removeBox { position:absolute; right:-10px; top:-10px; border-radius:10px; width:30px; height:20px; line-height:0; background-color:Red; color:White; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; text-align:center; border:solid 1px #600; }

    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/packman.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="main">
                                <label  >
            &nbsp;<img class="item" id="Img1" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Halil" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
            <img class="item" id="Img2" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Figen" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
            <img class="item" id="Img3" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Naz" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
            <img class="item" id="Img4" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Test" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
            <img class="item" id="Img5" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Huni" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
            <img class="item" id="Img6" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/red&text=Mavi" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />

            <img class="item" id="Img0" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Can" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" /></label></div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="packCount" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
        <button type="button" onclick="return createPackageClick();">Create Package</button>
        <asp:Button ID="createPackage" runat="server" alt="" text="postBack"/>
        <div id="packages">
            <div class="package" id="pack0">
                <div><label>Gönderecek Depo</label><asp:DropDownList ID="shipFr" runat ="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                <div><label>Teslimat Adresi</label><asp:DropDownList ID="shipTo" runat ="server"></asp:DropDownList></div>
                <button class="removeBox" type="button" onclick="return deletePack(this.parentNode);">x</button>
                <div class="items" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U87bs.jpg)

Comment: Why is your `Pack` function adding and changing properties on the `Pack` function? It also isn't returning anything. Basically, your code is dark and full of errors.

Comment: If i understand correct this id is wrong? cln.id = "pack" + packList.length;

Comment: ı fixed it , now can you look it again?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the use of your code, your question is why the elements do get the same ID.
The reason for this is:

```
cln.id = "pack" + packList.length;
```

"packList" is not initialized within your posted code, so we can't know, where it comes from. But you are depending the ID, which MUST be completely unique within the whole Page-Code, on the length of "packList" and the length doesn't change within the code.

But as some comments say, this seem to be no good code, from what we can guess. Maybe you want to write, what you are trying to create and we can guide you a better way :)

edit: I'm sorry to say, but as fas as my knowledge goes, you have some really mysterious (or wrong) code in there and i don't know if you maybe should start completely new... And read about Classes, Objects and Variable-Scope beforehand.

In the first segment of your code you seem to want to create a class "Pack" but to my knowledge this is not a valid way to write this.

Also

```
var pkgs = document.getElementById("packages")
```

makes no sense, since the scope is within the function and pkgs is never used after this line.

```
var pack=Pack();
```

Also makes no sense and

```
createPackageClick()
```

does return false in every case, never true or some value.
Also some functions return a value/bool only sometimes, tis makes no sense in programming.

If you edit your question and write exactly what you are trying to do, maybe one of us can give you some hints on what you will need. But as for this code, i think it's better to quote Mike C.:

> Basically, your code is dark and full of errors.

I thought it would get better but it didn't, sorry.

Comment: ı fixed it , now can you look it again?